# How can I return column names in dot notation in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I want to return column names into a table. But I also want to avoid redundancies like 'id' and 'id'.

I did:

```
INSERT INTO columns(name) 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name='contacts' or table_name='companies';
```

But as expected I get `id` from the first table showing up with the same field name.

How do I get it in the form: `contacts.id` and `companies.id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first try was very close. Just prepend the table_name and a dot:

```
INSERT INTO columns(name) 
SELECT CONCAT(TABLE_NAME,'.',COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name='contacts' or table_name='companies';
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'contacts' OR TABLE_NAME = 'companies' GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME;


INSERT INTO columns (name) SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='contacts' or TABLE_NAME='companies' GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME;
```